# Convergence of series of independent and positive random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

My question concerns Proposition 3.14 (series with positive terms) of Olav Kallenberg's 'Foundations of Modern Probability'. He states:

> Let $\xi_1,\xi_2 ...$ be independent $\mathbb{R}_+$-valued random
> variables. Then $\sum_n\xi_n<\infty$ a.s. iff $\sum_n E[\xi_n \wedge 1]<\infty$

I am confused by the $\wedge$ symbol. Unfortunately, he does not define it in his book and I am not an expert in probability theory. So, does someone know how $E[\xi_n \wedge 1]$ is defined?

Questions concerning the statement of Proposition 3.14 were posed in 
[Criteria for a.s. convergence of series of independent positive random variables.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2342636/criteria-for-a-s-convergence-of-series-of-independent-positive-random-variables) and 
[Convergence of expected value series.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2324234/convergence-of-expected-value-series) 
but they seem to contradict each other and do not solve my confusion.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Usually $a \wedge b =\min(a, b)$.

Comment: This would make sense! Thanks!